# html code for text positioning

Tags: html

On http://www.justcycles.ie/about-us-1-w.asp you will see that the writing is to the left too much what code do I need to move it across more central?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `margin: 0 auto` on the div direct below the `<div id="content">`

```
#content > div {margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0 auto` to the first child of `#content`.